# Jumping from an error/warning message to the offending line of code in the editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I have manually added ESLint to a Javascript project in VS Code. I also have the  VS Code ESLint extension installed.

After ESLint is run, the error and warning messages are shown in the Terminal, showing the file name and line/column numbers. Is it possible to click on an error message to jump to the offending line in the source file?

If I remember correctly, it was possible with JSLint that I used earlier, by Ctrl-clicking the line/column in the error message.

Comment: There is a built-in [visualstudio](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/formatters#visualstudio) formatter: if you click on a message in the VSCode output window it will take you to the respective line. Unfortunately, I don't know how to make it work with the ESLint extension.